# Datatables RowGroup show condition?

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm using [datatables with row grouping](https://datatables.net/extensions/rowgroup/examples/initialisation/customRow.html) and I want to show RowGroup only if there are two or more rows with the same value. The issue is that I don't know how to remove groups that have less than two rows.

This is what I got so far:

```
rowGroup: {
        startRender: function(rows, group) {
            if (rows.count() > 1) {
                return group + ' Dni';
            } else {
                console.log(rows); // Rows that I want to remove
                rows.remove(); // This aint working
            }
        },
        endRender: null,
        dataSrc: 8
    },
```

[Here is some wild example](https://datatables.net/extensions/rowgroup/examples/initialisation/customRow.html) that I don't understand.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the correct way of [row grouping](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html), much easier to understand.

you just need to modify this part that suits your need:

```
api.column(groupColumn, {page:'current'} ).data().each( function ( group, i ) {
            if ( last !== group ) {
                $(rows).eq( i ).before(
                    '<tr class="group"><td colspan="5">'+group+'</td></tr>'
                );

                last = group;
            }
        } );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rowGroup: {
    startRender: function(rows, group) {
        if (rows.count() > 1) {
            return group + ' Dni';
        }
        else{
           $(this).remove();
           return null;
        }
        return null;
    },
    endRender: null,
    emptyDataGroup: null,
    dataSrc: 8
},
```

Can you try this, please? Thanks!